# Batch Document Creation

Tags: text-editor, automation, document-management, microsoft-word

I draft letters that have the same basic language but with a few variations for 50+ people (e.g. name; bill amount etc). I edit these manually and feel that there must be an easier/more automated way to do this. I was wondering if someone could tell me a smarter way to get this done. Is there a way I can make the basic letter; leave fill-in-the-blanks; and have an excel file or something that will auto-fill the blanks w/ a column of info; and finally save the letters separately whether via Word/Adobe or any other solution?(I've got both on Mac and Windows machines but am open to other solutions). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, this is called [mail merge](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+mail+merge).

Comment: … and most office programs can do that: LibreOffice/OpenOffice, MS Office... Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like **howtos,** manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185).

Comment: If this is off topic here, could it be better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?  Should it be migrated?

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS-Office or LibreOffice you need to look at the help files for "[Mail Merge](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Mail_Merge_Wizard)" - there are lots of other ways to do this sort of task depending on the complexity of what you are doing.